Given Green's function, can I find the corresponding operator?
Green's function is the solution to the equation $L G(x;x') = \delta(x-x')$, where $L$ is a linear differential operator. Usually, we want to find the Green's function of a given $L$. Instead, if we are given a $G$, can we find the corresponding $L$? Specifically, consider the equation
$$L G(x,y;x',y')=\delta(x-x')\delta(y-y')$$ with
$$G(x,y;x',y')=e^{2i(x-x')(y-y')},$$
can we find the corresponding operator $L$ such that the green's function is the $G$ given above?
Aside: the form of the Green's function is the Moyal product of delta functions, i.e. $\delta(x-x')\star \delta(y-y')$. I'm curious if there exists an operator such that when it acts on the Moyal product of delta functions give simply the product of delta functions.

This is more mathematics than physics. Maybe try [math.se]?


Merely reverse the steps that got you there, in the first place.

Your framing your problem in terms of generic Green's functions formalism is superfluous.
I'll be using the direct, mainstream seat-of-the-pants formalism routinely employed in Groenewold (a.k.a. Moyal) $\star$ products. It is therefore pointless to be employing variables x-x' and y-y', so drop the primed variables and define, as you virtually did,
$$
\delta (x)\star \delta(y)= e^{{i\over 2} \partial_x \partial_y} \delta (x)  \delta(y)\\  = \delta\left(x+{i\over 2}\partial_y\right )~ \delta(y)= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int dk~~\delta\left(x-\tfrac{1}{2} k\right )~ e^{iky}\\
=\tfrac{1}{\pi} e^{i2xy}=\tfrac{1}{\pi} G(x,y) ~~~~~~\leadsto \\
\tfrac{1}{\pi}  e^{-{i\over 2} \partial_x \partial_y} ~~G(x,y)= \delta (x)  \delta(y).
$$
Let the bluestockings finesse conditions, domains and caveats: I'm answering the pre-migration question. You may then convert the differential operators to standard integral ones, to your satisfaction.

Perhaps somewhat naïve view is to look first at a discrete operator equation
$$
LG=1 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{k}L_{nk}G_{km}=\delta_{n,m}.
$$
This is trivially solved via the matrix inverse:
$$
L = G^{-1}
$$
The equation defining the Green's function in continuous space can be viewed as a matrix equation in infinite-dimensional Hilbert space (with a caveat that both position and time are basis indices):
$$
\int dx' L(x,x')G(x',x'')=\delta(x-x'')
$$
Solving this integral equation should then produce the inverse
$$
L(x,x')=G^{-1}(x,x').
$$
There is a nuance that the $L$ operators should be thought of not as differential forms, but as integral ones, which is not hard in terms of generalized functions:
$$
x\psi(x)=\int dx'x\delta(x-x')\psi(x'),\\
\partial_x\psi(x)=\int dx'\delta'(x-x')\psi(x'),
$$
and so on.

@TobiasFünke From the formulation of the Q., it is not evident that the OP understands that it is the question of inverse. Whether inverse is unique is a finer level of understanding, and I welcome you to add a higher-level answer.
